How to add a line item to an existing Woocommerce order via REST API?
I am looking to add a line item to an order. I am POSTing to this endpoint:
/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/7691

with some pretty basic json:
{
    "name": "Product Name",
    "product_id": 123,
    "quantity": 1
}

Authorization works, and the payload is accepted (200 OK), but no line_item is added.
I can GET the line_item data using the _fields:line_items parameter, but can't seem to figure out how to write to it. I was also told to try this endpoint:
/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/7691/line_items

... but it is not a recognized endpoint according to Woo REST API docs (404, rest_no_route).
Does anyone know how I might accomplish this, or if it's possible? Thanks for any help, I'm pretty new to working with APIs. Working with Bubble.io API Connector btw, but testing on Postman.

need more information on how you are making this request and the method you are using. GET/POST/PUT?? share some details and someone can help you

I am using the POST method, but I have also tried PUT and PATCH, none seem to work

Per the documentation, you need to submit a PUT request with the full json body because this type of update requires the FULL order details to be sent, assuming they implemented it correctly.
If you want to retrieve the existing order details so you don't have to hand type the whole thing, you can submit a GET request to ../wc-json/wc/3/orders/7691 and then reuse the response and add your new item.
You will add your new line item to the lineItems array using this schema
 {
      "id": 315,
      "name": "Woo Single #1",
      "product_id": 93,
      "variation_id": 0,
      "quantity": 2,
      "tax_class": "",
      "subtotal": "6.00",
      "subtotal_tax": "0.45",
      "total": "6.00",
      "total_tax": "0.45",
      "taxes": [
        {
          "id": 75,
          "total": "0.45",
          "subtotal": "0.45"
        }
      ],
      "meta_data": [],
      "sku": "",
      "price": 3
    }

Then you need the add it to the lineItems array and send this full representation
{
  "id": 727,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "number": "727",
  "order_key": "wc_order_58d2d042d1d",
  "created_via": "rest-api",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "status": "completed",
  "currency": "USD",
  "date_created": "2017-03-22T16:28:02",
  "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-22T19:28:02",
  "date_modified": "2017-03-22T16:30:35",
  "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-22T19:30:35",
  "discount_total": "0.00",
  "discount_tax": "0.00",
  "shipping_total": "10.00",
  "shipping_tax": "0.00",
  "cart_tax": "1.35",
  "total": "29.35",
  "total_tax": "1.35",
  "prices_include_tax": false,
  "customer_id": 0,
  "customer_ip_address": "",
  "customer_user_agent": "",
  "customer_note": "",
  "billing": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "969 Market",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
  },
  "shipping": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "969 Market",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US"
  },
  "payment_method": "bacs",
  "payment_method_title": "Direct Bank Transfer",
  "transaction_id": "",
  "date_paid": "2017-03-22T16:28:08",
  "date_paid_gmt": "2017-03-22T19:28:08",
  "date_completed": "2017-03-22T16:30:35",
  "date_completed_gmt": "2017-03-22T19:30:35",
  "cart_hash": "",
  "meta_data": [
    {
      "id": 13106,
      "key": "_download_permissions_granted",
      "value": "yes"
    },
    {
      "id": 13109,
      "key": "_order_stock_reduced",
      "value": "yes"
    }
  ],
  "line_items": [
    {
      "id": 315,
      "name": "Woo Single #1",
      "product_id": 93,
      "variation_id": 0,
      "quantity": 2,
      "tax_class": "",
      "subtotal": "6.00",
      "subtotal_tax": "0.45",
      "total": "6.00",
      "total_tax": "0.45",
      "taxes": [
        {
          "id": 75,
          "total": "0.45",
          "subtotal": "0.45"
        }
      ],
      "meta_data": [],
      "sku": "",
      "price": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 316,
      "name": "Ship Your Idea &ndash; Color: Black, Size: M Test",
      "product_id": 22,
      "variation_id": 23,
      "quantity": 1,
      "tax_class": "",
      "subtotal": "12.00",
      "subtotal_tax": "0.90",
      "total": "12.00",
      "total_tax": "0.90",
      "taxes": [
        {
          "id": 75,
          "total": "0.9",
          "subtotal": "0.9"
        }
      ],
      "meta_data": [
        {
          "id": 2095,
          "key": "pa_color",
          "value": "black"
        },
        {
          "id": 2096,
          "key": "size",
          "value": "M Test"
        }
      ],
      "sku": "Bar3",
      "price": 12
    }
  ],
  "tax_lines": [
    {
      "id": 318,
      "rate_code": "US-CA-STATE TAX",
      "rate_id": 75,
      "label": "State Tax",
      "compound": false,
      "tax_total": "1.35",
      "shipping_tax_total": "0.00",
      "meta_data": []
    }
  ],
  "shipping_lines": [
    {
      "id": 317,
      "method_title": "Flat Rate",
      "method_id": "flat_rate",
      "total": "10.00",
      "total_tax": "0.00",
      "taxes": [],
      "meta_data": []
    }
  ],
  "fee_lines": [],
  "coupon_lines": [],
  "refunds": [],
  "_links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/727"
      }
    ],
    "collection": [
      {
        "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders"
      }
    ]
  }
}'


i reviewed the api docs a bit more and it seems quite a few properties are readOnly, so those do not have to be included in your PUT request.  If you do send them, they will be ignored.  https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#order-properties

I did realize some were read-only, but I didn't realize I had to send the entire payload + the extra line item. Unfortunate I can't use the PATCH method, but thanks for the reply!
